# StaticLayout vs TextView

Tags: android, textview, exoplayer, staticlayout

Why do we need a `StaticLayout`? 
What does it do that we can't do with a `TextView`?

The reason I'm asking this is because that I use"Exo Player" which uses `StaticLayout` to show the subtitles And I am having some troubles with RTL on it. The punctuation are not displayed correctly so I want to replace it with `TextView`. Any reason I shouldn't do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TextView` is a `View` with all the overhead of a `View` object, and all the abilities of a `View` object. `StaticLayout` is meant for drawing fixed text directly on to a canvas.